# I have this problem with opencv python on Macbook

Tags: python, opencv

My problem is when I try to run this code on my Mac, the camera turns on the green light but it doesn't open at all. I have no idea why this is happing. I tried a lot of things but nothing worked for me, I am just thinking the new update from Apple messed up some stuff, because it used to work before.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I'm going through the exact same thing, did you find a solution ??

Comment: I recommend you to check this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64838511/opencv-imshow-crashes-python-launcher-on-macos-11-0-1-big-sur

Answer (score 0):

In mac you have to use the `Mac Terminal` for the `cv2` library since currently no other terminal to my knowledge asks for the camera permission.

Comment: I did use it but still no success with it

Comment: Is it showing any error?
Most likely your mac blocks the webcam access. Check System Pref -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Camera.

Comment: I have already done that and my terminal allowed to access the camera. But every time I run my code the python launcher pops up on the toolbar at the bottom of the screen but nothing happens.

Comment: No answer then.